# Heroku error code H13 when trying to open app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, hosting

I tried deploying my node.js app to Heroku which worked ok until i try to connect to it (open the app).
The error is get is as follows:

```
2021-02-18T00:16:03.975921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=gtdb.herokuapp.com request_id=16579da6-aa8e-4184-8e1c-7ac9680d0078 fwd="-myipaddresswhichidontwanttoshare-" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
app = express();
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./server.crt")
};
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Of course i searched for the issue and some sites say that it could be a timeout and their errors had connect and service times of up to 30000ms where a timeout would make perfect sense but im far away from 30s so i dont know what the issue is here.
The app does not crash after it throws that error.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku servers are controlled at their load balancers which terminates SSL and sends the request to your server without SSL.

So you should be using the `HTTP` server instead of `HTTPS` on Heroku.

You can use this package https://github.com/paulomcnally/node-heroku-ssl-redirect/ to redirect any incoming HTTP traffic from the client to HTTPS.

https://mishkaorakzai.medium.com/how-to-redirect-your-node-js-app-hosted-on-heroku-from-http-to-https-50ef80130bff

Comment: thanks for your answer. when i try to implement the package you recommended i get the following error: `app.use(sslRedirect()); TypeError: sslRedirect is not a function`

Comment: @KnechtNoobrecht https://github.com/paulomcnally/node-heroku-ssl-redirect/issues/17#issuecomment-734242868
`import herokuSSLRedirect from 'heroku-ssl-redirect'
const sslRedirect = herokuSSLRedirect.default` or `const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect').default`

Comment: When i try to import it, i get the error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`. So i changed my file to app.mjs, set "type" to "module" in package.json and added these lines of codes so my other imports work:  `import { createRequire } from 'module'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);`
Now when i try to import my mongodb models from another file `import {Book} from "./models/book.js";` i get `SyntaxError: The requested module './models/book.js' does not provide an export named 'Book'`. 
The file i want to import ends with `module.exports = Book;`

Comment: Solved using `const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect').default`, not importing it.